# HTML5 tags in IE 8 & IE 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Hi as I mentioned in title, 
in Firefox (firebug), IE-9/10, Chrome it shows properly like:

```
<footer>
    <div>...</div>
</footer>
```

where as in IE-8/7 it shows like:

```
<footer />
    <div>...</div>
</footer/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE7/8 do not support the new HTML5 tags like `footer`.

If you use them, you will get issues like this, and rendering glitches as a result.

There are work-arounds in the form of the [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) polyfill scripts. Use one of these libraries to add support for HTML5 tags to old IE versions.

If you're not prepared to use a Javascript library to fix IE's HTML5 support, the other option is to stop using these tags and switch back to using `<div>` tags for everything, with classes to identify them semantically.

Comment: html5shiv is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the HTML 5 shim and selectivizr to add CSS support for advanced selector types (e.g. :nth-child) to old versions of IE.

http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js
https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/blob/master/selectivizr.js

Include both of these in your page in IE conditional comments and it should fix your problem.

Comment: You don't need Selectivizr to apply styles to HTML5 elements using CSS.

Comment: Quite right. Sorry brain fart there. Have updated my reply. Thanks @BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

I just use this to enable HTML5 elements in IE:

```
<script>
'article aside footer header nav section time'.replace(/\w+/g,function(n){document.createElement(n)});
<script>
```