# HTML5 template not working on Internet Explorer, how to solve it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web-component, html5-template

I made a template in HTML5 which is working with Chrome and Firefox but not working with Internet Explorer (tested on IE 8).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: first of all, we need some codes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [html 5 tags in IE 8 and IE 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680929/html-5-tags-in-ie-8-and-ie-7)

Answer (score 9):

just add "display:none" to your templates. Works for i.e. 11

```
<template id="fancyTemplate" style="display:none"></template>
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! [Even  IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template) displayes `<template>` content, regardless of it being in `<head>`.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you Neovov's polyfill:
https://github.com/neovov/template-element-polyfill

NB: There's a bug in IE 11: it moves <template> under the <body> element before rendering the DOM! So the parentNode attribute is wrong, and nesting will fail.
You can see it in the [F12] Tool.

Comment: This is probably as good as it goes, but it's still limited. Because the stuff inside the template tag is rendered, you have to be careful to still follow HTML nesting rules -- despite the fact that a properly functioning Template element can ignore those rules.  I'm getting "unexpected end tag" and similar on some of my pages.

Comment: For example: I've been trying to put a table row in a Template.  Because (I think) a TR cannot exist just inside the Body, IE is removing the TR and the TD and just leaving the contents of the TD.  (Even with the shivs or polyfills, IE basically sees Template as a sort of Div-like object, and the HTML hierarchy kicks in)

Comment: You're right, it's not possible to fully polyfill a template tag

Comment: Right. Just trying to give people a heads up in case they're expecting this to be a full replacement. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Get a copy of [html4shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), and use it where IE is less than 9:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ie.css" type="text/css"> <script src="scripts/ie/html5shiv.min.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @knotty sure, just reinvent everthing html5shiv does :)

Comment: knotty is right, it is not worth the effort to rewrite html5shiv. BTW why IE8? That is a version from 6 years ago. Nothing supported modern HTML5 back then. If you need a free resource to get modern internet explorer versions to test, visit http://modern.ie and there are free virtual machines available.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for the [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

It *'enables'* all the html5 elements, which aren't available in the old internet explorer versions.

Comment: `<template>` [is not available in ANY version of IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=template), not only in old versions. Not quite sure if html5shiv solves the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace `<template>` tag by `<script>`

```
<script id="fancyTemplate"></script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a type because default is javascript.  
    
`<script type="text/x-template" id="fancyTemplate"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the element using CSS: `template { display:none !important; }`

And if you need to access/clone the content like natively possible in other browsers, use this polyfill: https://github.com/jeffcarp/template-polyfill

> But keep in mind the content of the `<template>` can still be found in the DOM and is executed - preventing exactly that is the main goal of the tag. No polyfill can stop that from happening, IE is once again slowing down modern web development.