# HTML5 Section Internet Explorer 8 Alternative

Tags: html

How can I use

```
<section> </section>
```

in Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML 5 tags in IE 8 and IE 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680929/html-5-tags-in-ie-8-and-ie-7)

Comment: http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

If you ask that if HTML 5 special feature like `<video>` or `<canvas>` compatible with IE8. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5) for compatibility question.